# Data structure/model of score keeping app for games (avoiding many-to-many-to-many)

Tags: database-design, data-structures, relational-database, entity-relationship

I'm exploring a simple score-keeping app for playing the card game Rummy just as an exercise. I'm building it for iOS, but that is kind of irrelevant as it uses a SQLite data store so the data structure is applicable in any environment. Let me setup a use-case:

To start keeping score, you first set up your players. I'd like it to be possible to persist players so you can track stats and such. So, you either create new players or select existing.

Then, as you play, you add rounds with scores for each player.

When finished the game, players, and scores are all saved so you can view a log of past games.

The issue I'm running into is that a player can play many games, which have many rounds. But, when viewing a game, it has many rounds, with each round having many players (to display their scores).

Building an ERD for this shows how out-of-hand my perception of this data structure will be.

[image: Silly ERD]

It seems like I'm spinning in circles. Are there any examples of structuring this data, or can anyone show me where I'm getting off track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Facts*

- **Game** exists.
- **Game** has **GameRound**.
- **Player** exists.
- **Player** plays **GameRound**.

---

*Constraints*

- `It is possible that some` **Game** has `more than one` **GameRound**.
- `It is possible that some` **Player** plays `more than one` **GameRound**
  `and that for some` **GameRound**, `more than one` **Player** plays `that` **GameRound**.

---

*Logical*

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Very clear and organized. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the `Player` table to be the pool of possible players for a `Game` then you need a `GamePlayer` table between the `Game` and `Player` tables to identify the set of players for that particular game. This table can also hold the `position` of the four players at the table for that game.

For the PK on this table you could use the combination of GameID and PlayerID, or add an auto-generated ID. IF you go with the latter option (which is what I prefer), you still should have a unique index on the `GameID/PlayerID` combo. `GameID/Position` is also a valid candidate for the PK as each game can only have each position filled once.

I would remove the Round table completely and in its place add a `Score` Table, with `RoundNum` as a column. That `Score` would have a foreign key reference back to the `GamePlayer` table (as only players in that game can actually score points).

Again you have a choice for PK on this table. `GamePlayerID/RoundNum` has to be unique and is a candidate for the PK, but I would go with the auto-generated ID. And once again you should have a unique index on the `GamePlayerID/RoundNum` combo.

With Those four tables you can resolve all the M:M relationships.

[image]